# Unable to validate hyphens

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to validate name which contains "alphanumeric characters, supported symbols, and space". Here I need to allow only a single `hyphen(-)`, but not a double `hyphen(--)`.

This is my code as follows:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
  'alphanumeric_only',
  function (val, elem) {
    return this.optional(elem) || /^[^*~<^>+(\--)/;|.]+$/.test(val);
  },
  $.format("shouldn't contain *.^~<>/;|")
);
```

The above code, doesn't even allow a single `hyphen(-)`. How do I allow a single hyphen, but prevent a double hyphen. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this, you need a negative [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/^(?!.*--)[^*~<^>+()\/;|.]+$/
```

should do it.

**Explanation:**

```
^                 # Start of string
(?!               # Assert it's impossible to match the following:
 .*               #  any string, followed by
 --               #  two hyphens
)                 # End of lookahead
[^*~<^>+()\/;|.]+ # Match a string consisting only of characters other than these
$                 # End of string
```

Not that this might fail if your string can contain newlines. If it can, use

```
/^(?![\s\S]*--)[^*~<^>+()\/;|.]+$/
```

Answer (score 4):

I advise you to use white list instead of blacklist. However this is working:

```
        <input type="text" id="validate"/>
    <script>
        $('#validate').keyup(function(){
            val = this.value;
            if(/([*.^~<>/;|]|--)/.test(val)) this.style.backgroundColor='red';
            else this.style.backgroundColor='';
        });
    </script>
```